# How to make cd work inside of a bash script

Tags: bash

Problem Statement : Create an alias cdff which will find a first occurance of a directory (that's given as a parameter) and assign it to a variable FILEPATH.

Alias cdf='cd $FILEPATH' should change to that directory.

For example, command 'cdff TestDir' should set FILEPATH=Dir1/Dir2/TestDir

So if I want to go to TestDir, I just run 'cdff TestDir' followed by 'cdf' and expect to change directory to Dir1/Dir2/TestDir since I am exporting variable FILEPATH

In .bashrc I am creating this alias,

> alias cdff='./cdfindfirstoccurance.sh'
>
> alias cdf='cd $FILEPATH'

cdfindfirstoccurance.sh

> export FILEPATH=`find . -name "*$1*"  -print -quit` #Set the variable FILEPATH to be later used by alias cdf
>
> echo "FILEPATH : ${FILEPATH}"
>
> #cd ${FILEPATH} #I understand why this wouldn't work.

Since I am exporting the variable FILEPATH when I executed cdff, I was expecting alias cdf to just work.
After I execute cdff when I print "echo $FILEPATH", Its just empty.

EDIT:
A better way to solve this is most welcome.
Right now the only way is to use find command and then copy the output with mouse and give it to cd.
I am trying to avoid using mouse and don't want to type the entire path either.

EDIT2:
As mentioned in the comments, changing the alias from

> alias cdff='./cdfindfirstoccurance.sh'

to

> alias cdff='source cdfindfirstoccurance.sh'

worked just fine.

Comment: `cdf` doesn't see the value of `$FILENAME` set by the script, it's not export that you need, it's sourcing the script (`. /path/to/script` with a space after the dot ; you can use `source` instead of the dot if you want to be more explicit, but that's a bashism while the dot is POSIX-defined). Using a relative path in the alias is also most likely a mistake since that means it will only work if you are located in the directory where the script is.

Comment: Try this: `alias cdff='source /home/me/cdfindfirstoccurance.sh'` where /home/me in reality is what `echo $HOME` prints.

Comment: @Roadowl, That works. Thanks a lot. I knew there was a better way of doing this!

Comment: @Aaron, I changed to relative path to keep the question simple. Thanks. Sourcing the command instead of running it worked just fine.

Comment: Please [format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). You should almost always [use functions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/080) instead of aliases in scripts. You only need to `export` variables if they're needed in the environment of children of the current process.